# Конфигурирование log4J 2 без файла конфигураций

Tags: java, log4j2

**Как сконфигурировать log4J 2 через код?**

Недавно наткнулся на проблему того, что мне надо сконфигурировать log4J в соответствии с запускаемыми параметрами приложения *(Напр: `app -console debug` - выводить всю дебаговую информацию `app -file all -console warn` - писать в файл весь лог, а в консоль выводить только придупреждения.)*. У меня сразу появилась идея создания разных xml и использования из в соответствии с запускаемыми параметрами, но мне тогда надо их написать достаточно много, не учитывая того, что я собираюсь сделать поддержку сохранения логов в каталог, зависящий от подаваемых параметров и ОС юзера.
Ища в интернете инфу о подобном конфигурировании, и найдя очень мало [полезных](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406485/how-to-create-log4j2-appender-from-java-code) примеров или пояснений, я начал думать, что это неправильная идея. Если это и есть так, то поясните почему и предложите альтернативу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В официальной документации довольно [подробно описаны](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) способы с помощью которых можно сконфигурировать log4j2 посредством Java API. Начальные настройки вы можете задать через ConfigurationBuilder, или загрузить из файла. Менять их можно в том числе в рантайме.